# Categorial definition of free products?

Tags: category-theory, definition

If $X$ and $Y$ are objects of a **concrete** category $\mathcal{C}$, is there an accepted definition of "free product of $X$ and $Y$," generalizing the  in the special case where $\mathcal{C}$ is the concrete category of groups? See also, [free product of groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product).

**Edit.** In $\mathbf{Grp},$ the free product is just the coproduct, but I see no reason why this should be the "right" definition of "free product" general. Free products ought to have a special relationship to free objects. If we can find that relationship, then we can either prove that coproducts always enjoy that relationship, or else, find a case where they do not.

Comment: Is there some particular feature of the free product as a *concrete* object you're keen to capture? I'm guessing you already know it's the coproduct in $\mathbf{Grp}$.

Comment: "but why should coproducts give the "right" answer in general?" For which question?

Comment: I don't see a way to argue against a coproduct being the correct generalization except to point out uses of a free product that don't come from the universal property of a coproduct. Unfortunately I don't know nearly enough group theory to start looking for examples :p

Comment: well actually the free product is by definition the coproduct in $\mathbf{GRP}$, I don't how how you think about the free product in a formal way, but I think of it as being the coproduct.

Comment: "Free products ought to have a special relationship to free objects. " No, except for the trivial statement $F(S \coprod T) = F(S) \coprod F(T)$ which holds for any left adjoint $F$. As long as you don't give a precise meaning of "free product", there is no question to be answered.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, why on earth not?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, also I think it is a grand conceptual mistake to think that every legitimate question pins down all its terms 100% accurately to the point where a brainless unthinking computer can decide the correctness of an answer. Demanding that all questions have this property can only be antithetical to progress and understanding.

Comment: This is true, but doesn't change the fact that your question is currently quite meaningless. It is $\approx$ "Is there a categorical definition of the coproduct in the category of groups." ...

Comment: @Zlatan: Or the free product is defined as a particular group formed out of reduced words of a over a pair of groups. I've never seen a text *define* it in terms of its universal property.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, its more like "is there an **accepted** definition of [term]" with a bit more fluff afterwards which is my (admittedly rather lame) attempt at pinning down what properties I want [term] to satisfy. Anyway, I think the word *accepted* gives the question more objectivity than you're giving it credit for.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine: now you see one, and in fact a very standard text: Robinson, a course in the theory of groups (admittedly its not a beginners text, but this is not relevant).

Comment: @Zlatan: Aaaand totally added to my Amazon wish list. :D

Comment: Since you haven't defined what "free product" means in other categories, it's not clear why you don't accept the coproduct as the "free product."

Answer (score 4):

Yes of course, even for any category: it is called the coproduct :)

Comment: And for this reason it should not be called free **product**. I hope that some day this unfortunate terminology will be replaced by the correct one ... (of course I know that the terminology is motivated by the element structure of the coproduct, but often the element structure doesn't really tell us what an object is.)

Comment: Well, the name "free product" comes from pre-category thinking about groups, no doubt. And if you are studying groups before category theory, "free product" is a nice generalization of "free group." Trying to explain the term "co-product" might be difficult without category theory.

Answer (score 2):

Most notions of "freeness" start with a functor $G:\mathcal C\to \mathcal D$ and finding an adjoint $F:\mathcal D\to \mathcal C$ with $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(FD,C)\equiv \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal D}(D,GC)$. For example, with $\mathcal C$ the category of groups, and $\mathcal D$ the category of sets, and $G$ the forgetful functor sending a group to the underlying set.

Then the diagonal functor $G:\mathcal C\to \mathcal C^2$ with $C\mapsto (C,C)$ has as its corresponding $F$ the coproduct.

Comment: I replaced a few instances of the word "function" with "functor." Is that okay?

Comment: No problem, @user18921.

Comment: My only issue with this is that we haven't really linked coproducts to free objects at all. I think we should assume $\mathcal{C}$ is concrete over $\mathbf{Set}$, and I think that the forgetful functor $\mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$ should play a role.

Answer (score 1):

For the question "what's the link between a free product and a free object?", the answer is given in the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product), before "contents":

> The point is that a disjoint union of groups is not a group but it is a groupoid. A groupoid  G has a universal group  U(G)  and the universal group of a disjoint union of groups is the free (= coproduct) of the groups.

*Remarks:*

1. It seems that here $U(-)$ denotes the free functor left adjoint to the forgetful functor $ \mathbf{Grp}\longrightarrow \mathbf{Grpoid}$
2. The disjoint union is the in $\mathbf{Grpoid}$

To me, the OP's question is obviously: is there a distinct categorical notion of free product (distinct from coproduct in general but such that for groups they coincide, exactly as coproduct and products in other examples)?